# Linear program with parameter $t$ as coefficient of basic variable

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

Consider the following linear problem

$$\max tx_1+x_2\\ s.t. 4x_1+3x_2\le12 \\ 3x_1+4x_2\le12\\ x_1,x_2\ge0$$

where the parameter $t$ grows exponentially $t\in[1,\infty).$

Find the sequence of basic optimal solutions.

**Attempt:**

First we should convert to standar form

$$\max tx_1+x_2\\ s.t.\ 4x_1+3x_2+x_3=12 \\ 3x_1+4x_2+x_4=12\\ x_1,x_2\ge0$$

Then, I am not sure how should I proceed.

I've solved exercise where you have say $3$ instead of $t$ and then you change $3$ by $4$ and then analyze how the final simplex tableau changes, as it is a coefficient of a *basic variable* the optimality and factibility might both be affected.

But this could be fixed by using again simplex method or dual-simplex in the final tableau.

My question is how should I proceed in this case where there is a $t$ instead of a number?

Could someone help me please?

I would really appreciate any help you're willing to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Just iterate through a couple of times, and see how the process depends on $t$, and where you end up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work geometrically. The domain is given in the picture below :

[image]

Now, the gradient of $f(x_1,x_2) = tx_1+x_2$ equals $\pmatrix{t\\1}$.

If $t=1$, the optimum lies at the intersection of $3x_1+4x_2=12$ and $4x_1+3x_2=12$, i.e. $(\frac{12}{7},\frac{12}{7})$.

If $t=\frac{4}{3}$, the gradient is orthogonal to $4x_1+3x_2=12$, which means that all points on this line are optimal, in particular $(\frac{12}{7},\frac{12}{7})$ and $(3,0)$.

So for any $t\in [1,\frac{4}{3}[$, $(\frac{12}{7},\frac{12}{7})$ is the optimal point.

Then, as $t$ increases, the gradient points towards $(3,0)$.

---

Note that this matches gt6989b's answer : solving $3t = \frac{12(t+1)}{7}$ for $t$ yields $t=\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the sequence of basic optimal solutions?

Comment: $(12/7,12/7)$, $(3,0)$, $(3,0)$, $(3,0)$,.......

Comment: ok. Could you explain this part if $t=1$ the optimum lies at the intersection of $3x_1+4x_2=12$ and $3x_1+4x_2=12$ ?

Comment: If $t=1$, the gradient is $(1,1)$, so it points in the direction of the line $x_2=x_1$. Since $(12/7,12/7)$ lies on this line, the gradient points towards  $(12/7,12/7)$.

Comment: ok I understand that part, I don't see how the gradient points towards $(3,0)$ when $t$ increases; there is a constant $1$, how can you know that it will point towards $(3,0)$ ?

Comment: For $t>1$, it doesn't point exactly towards $(3,0)$ (except when $t=\infty$). Ask yourself, how far can you go in the domain in the gradient's direction ? You can go up to $(3,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one high-level approach. Your region looks like this:

[image: LP Plot]

Easy to see $(0,0)$ produces the optimization value 0, so only 3 points are in play: $(3,0),(0,3)$ and $(12/7,12/7)$.

Which one will get chosen and how will the optimization converge?

**UPDATE**

You are maximizing $f(x_1,x_2) = tx_1 + x_2$. It produces the following values at the vertices:

$$
f(0,3) = 3, f(3,0) = 3t, f(12/7,12/7) = (t+1)12/7
$$

As $t$ evolves, which of the values is larger?

Comment: $(3,0)$ will get chosen, I don't know how the optimization will converge. How?

Comment: Nice picture ! ^^

Comment: @Alt. see update, not so simple

Comment: $f(3,0)=3t$ is the larger value

Comment: Am I correct? ${}$

Comment: What would be the sequence of basic optimal solutions?

Comment: @Alt. plug in $(3,0)$ and find the remaining slacks to get the optimal solution completely.